# Tool to show memory that would be freed if I terminate a process and its sub processes?

Tags: command-line, memory, utilities, shared-memory

I know that it's a bit tricky to show the memory that a process is *using* due to the fact that there is memory shared.

But when I look at memory diagnostics, it's normally because my memory is getting low. So the information I actually need in these cases is:

**How much memory would be *freed* if I terminate a process and its sub processes?**

I'd assume (hope ;-)) that this question could be easier to answer as the kernel must know which shared parts of the memory can be freed, if I terminate a given set of processes.

I did some search but didn't find a helpful tool yet. Is there something like this already?